# Calling variables from User Defined functions

Tags: python-3.x

The code is probably buggy I just used it to illustrate my point(but feel free to point out any mistakes) I need to know how to call a variable i defined as an input in a user defined function. at the moment my error is "global name 'name' is not defined"

```
import time

def createIdentity():
    print ("Please Enter your details below")
    time.sleep(1)
    name = input("What is your name?")
    time.sleep(1)
    age = input("How old are you?")
    time.sleep(1)
    gender = input("Are you male or female?")

def recallIdentity():
    print("Your name is " + str(name) + "you are " + str(age) + "And you are a " +     str(gender) + "!")


createIdentity()
recallIdentity()
```

Comment: Actually, it is a good example where classes, instance variables, and methods fit. The things you want to achieve are natural for simplest clases. You want to put together the data and the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the values inputed in createIdentity, and then pass the returned values to recallIdentity. A variable name that's defined in one function is *not* the same variable as a variable with the same name in a different function.

I'd do it with a dictionary, thusly:

```
import time

def createIdentity():
    user = dict()
    print ("Please Enter your details below")
    time.sleep(1)
    user['name'] = input("What is your name?")
    time.sleep(1)
    user['age'] = input("How old are you?")
    time.sleep(1)
    user['gender'] = input("Are you male or female?")
    return user

def recallIdentity(user_out):
    print("Your name is " + user_out['name'] + "you are " + user_out['age'] + "And you are a " + user_out['gender'] + "!")

user_dict = createIdentity()
recallIdentity(user_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton I will definitely use this if it's not to much trouble out of curiosity is there something other than libraries you would have used?

Comment: Libraries? Do you mean dictionaries? If so, you could also do something like `return name, age, gender`, then captured the return values with `a, b, c = createIdentity()`. Then you could pass some or all of them to another function.

Comment: Thanks again and yes sorry I've been dictionaries I've been stuffing about with making my own libraries to import from so that's where I got mixed up

Answer (score 0):

By default, functions are entirely self-contained. You have to either compute your variables, or pass them in as parameters, or return them from other functions (another form of computing).

However, there are such things as global variables. With global variables, you can set them in one function, access them in another function, and the value will carry over.

In python, you must tell python the variable is global inside each function where you use it as a global.

For example:

```
def f():
  x = 1    # NOT global

def g():
  global x
  x = 1    # Global x.

def h():
  print("X is %d" % x)   # NOT a global x

def i():
  global x
  print("X is %d" % x)    # Global x.
```

In your example, I believe you want the global behaviors - the g() and i() functions.

Comment: Thank you for this it is much simpler that using dictionaries though I think I will look into dictionaries just to expand my vocab

Comment: Please, try to avoid `global` if possible. This was one of the reasons of so called *software crisis* in the past. You want to create the object of the class.