# Defining a variable with pre-entered information

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this code but I want to make it so that once the persons details are entered i can insert they're name to retrieve their details for say a contact list or a reference for sending e-mails to people so I can remember who they are. e.g. Ill type someones full name (Jennifer Craig) and get a list of pre-entered details. Pleas help. 
                                                 Sincerely
                                                     Elemere

```
import time

def createIdentity():
    print ("Please Enter your details below")
    time.sleep(1)
    name = input("What is your name?")
    time.sleep(1)
    age = input("How old are you?")
    time.sleep(1)
    gender = input("Are you male or female?")

def recallIdentity():
    print("Your name is " + str(name) + "you are " + str(age) + "And you are a " +     str(gender) + "!")


createIdentity()
recallIdentity()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling variables from User Defined functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826672/calling-variables-from-user-defined-functions)

Comment: You should consider making these methods part of a class and then use `self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You can use this to store keys, and map values to them.

Demo- you could retrieve the values like this:

```
>>> contacts = {'Jennifer Craig': [30, Female], 'John Doe': [40, 'Male']}
>>> contacts['Jennifer Craig']
[30, Female]
```

And add them like this:

```
>>> name = 'Mark Smith'
>>> age = 25
>>> gender = 'Male'
>>> contacts[name] = [age, gender]
>>> contacts
{'Jennifer Craig': [30, Female], 'Mark Smith': [25, 'Male'], 'John Doe': [40, 'Male']}
```

Comment: Thank you I don't quite understand this but that's good now I can look in to dictionaries and add another tool to my bag of tricks.